# Alternative to resetting the asp "Windows Services" every few days

Tags: asp.net, windows-services, recycle

One of my site is on a shared hosting and every few days the site will stop working.
The pages will simply stop loading.

After contacting my host they suggested that I disable/re-enable from their hosting
management tool the windows services for my site every time this happens.
In the list on their website I have: ASP, ASP.net and 2 other that I don't need.
When I disable and than immediately re-enable the 2 asp services the site *does* start 
working again right away.

I'm under the impression that this is a probably due to a wrong configuration of the
application pool my domain is using but they're refusing to give details. No
automatic recycle maybe?

***Beside changing host***, do you have any suggestion about this problem?
Do you believe it's an app pool setup issue like I do or do you have any other
idea on what else could be causing this issue and/or ideas for a permanent solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is something wrong with your code. I once ran into a similar issue with my web host and found out later that the app was leaking memory due to some resources that were opened and never closed. I suggest you inspect the code a bit more.